# How do I modify a generator in Python?

Tags: python, generator

Is there a common interface in Python that I could derive from to modify behavior of a generator?

For example, I want to modify an existing generator to insert some values in the stream and remove some other values.

How do I do that?

Thanks, Boda Cydo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the functions provided by [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) to take a generator and produce a new generator.

For example, you can use [takewhile](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) until a predicate is no longer fulfilled, and [chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) on a new series of values.

Take a look at the documentation for other examples, including things like [ifilter](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter), [dropwhile](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) and [islice](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to name just a few more.

Answer (score 7):

You can just wrap the generator in your own generator.

```
from itertools import count

def odd_count():
    for i in count():
        if i % 2:
            yield i
```

Comment: Wow, that is amazing, i didn't know i could wrap them so easily! Thanks!