# How to write a generator that returns ALL-BUT-LAST items in the iterable in Python?

Tags: python

I asked some similar questions [1, 2] yesterday and got great answers, but I am not yet technically skilled enough to write a generator of such sophistication myself.

How could I write a generator that would raise StopIteration if it's the last item, instead of yielding it?

I am thinking I should somehow ask two values at a time, and see if the 2nd value is StopIteration. If it is, then instead of yielding the first value, I should raise this StopIteration. But somehow I should also remember the 2nd value that I asked if it wasn't StopIteration.

I don't know how to write it myself. Please help.

For example, if the iterable is [1, 2, 3], then the generator should return 1 and 2.

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

[1] [How do I modify a generator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421355/how-do-i-modify-a-generator-in-python)

[2] [How to determine if the value is ONE-BUT-LAST in a Python generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421368/how-to-determine-if-the-value-is-one-but-last-in-a-python-generator)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def allbutlast(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    current = it.next()
    for i in it:
        yield current
        current = i


>>> list(allbutlast([1,2,3]))
[1, 2]
```

This will iterate through the entire list, and return the previous item so the last item is never returned.
Note that calling the above on both [] and [1] will return an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

First off, is a generator really needed? This sounds like the perfect job for Python’s [slices syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq):

```
result = my_range[ : -1]
```

I.e.: take a range form the first item to the one before the last.

Comment: Thanks for the friendly response, but a generator is absolutely needed, not a slice.

Answer (score 2):

The [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project has a tool that emulates `itertools.islice` with support for negative indices:

```
import more_itertools as mit

list(mit.islice_extended([1, 2, 3], None, -1))
# [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

the `itertools` module shows a `pairwise()` method in its recipes. adapting from this recipe, you can get your generator:

```
from itertools import *

def n_apart(iterable, n):
    a,b = tee(iterable)
    for count in range(n):
        next(b)
    return zip(a,b)

def all_but_n_last(iterable, n):
    return (value for value,dummy in n_apart(iterable, n))
```

the `n_apart()` function return pairs of values which are n elements apart in the input iterable, ignoring all pairs . `all_but_b_last()` returns the first value of all pairs, which incidentally ignores the n last elements of the list.

```
>>> data = range(10)
>>> list(data)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(n_apart(data,3))
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9)]
>>> list(all_but_n_last(data,3))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> 
>>> list(all_but_n_last(data,1))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
gen = (x for x in iterable[:-1])
```

Comment: Two problems: a) not all iterables can be sliced, b) if `iterable` is a large list, `iterable[:-1]` will create a large copy of most of that list, which will then be thrown away in a generator. There's got to be a better way to make this one-liner generator work. (But not `itertools.islice`, which doesn't support negative arguments. My bad.)

Comment: The argument with the large list may be applicable in general, but as the OP wants a generator that will stop at the last-but-one element, the list will presumably be traversed entirely, so that's not too much wasted space.

Comment: Hm, on second thought, it is wasted space. :) The iterable contains all we need, no need to copy it. Thx for the hint, Chris.